# Good c++ profiler for GCC

Tags: c++, profiling

I tried to find a related question but all previous questions are about profilers for native c++ in windows. I googled a while and learned about gprof, but the output of gprof actually contained lot of obscure internal functions. Is there a good opensource c++ profiler with good documentation?

Comment: You can also try manual profiling with http://code.google.com/p/profiny Its overhead should be really small compared to other tools.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can I use to profile C++ code in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Valgrind

I totally recommend this 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind

Answer (score 6):

Don't use **gprof**, [for the reasons given here](http://archive.fo/9r927).

What you need are stackshots, [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024). One way to take stackshots is the **pstack** utility. Another way is to use "Pause" or ctrl-break under the debugger. Also **lsstack**, if you can get a copy.

If you want to spend money, [RotateRight makes a nice tool based on stack sampling called Zoom](http://www.rotateright.com/).

Comment: @MarkJ.Adams: They keep doing that, taking down unpopular stuff. I put in the archived link.

Answer (score 3):

Compile using the flag  `-pg` and use [`gprof`](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the KDE library dependencies, [KCachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) is very useful with the added visualization. It depends on Callgrind and Valgrind, as one could have guessed, so no special compiler flags required during compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard oprofile is really, really good for real time apps. Linux only though, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

How much detail do you need in your profile reports. If you just want to do some really simple time profiling for a few functions, then the new functionality available via the C++11 `chrono` classes makes it easy to profile in a cross platform, cross compiler way.

See [this article](http://audioplastic.org/blog/2012/12/31/matlab-like-profiling-in-c-plus-plus-using-raii/) for some simple profiling code that works similarly to Matlab's super easy to use `tic` and `toc` functions.